# Select where in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

How can I select all records where the id is in the array?

So if I have an array with the values 1,25,2,12,1859 and 192: all the records with the id's should be returned.

Now I have this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN(".implode(",",$my_array).")";
```

But that doesn't work. It only returns one value.

Comment: Could you show more of the code as well as `print_r($my_array)`?

Comment: Sure: Output is: Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => 26 ) And it only returns 24 in the query.

Comment: `implode(",",$my_array)` is only returning `24` or the query is only selecting the row with ID 24?

Comment: Well, perhaps there is another error in my code. I'm trying to find it, if not, I ask again here. Thanks;-)

Comment: what does `var_dump($query);` give?

Answer (score 0):

Add the quotes in the query

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN('".implode("','",$my_array)."')";
```

Comment: You don't need the quotes if values are integers.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to first implode the my_array, store it in a variable and use is inside your query.

Example:

```
<?php 
$my_array[0] = 24;
$my_array[1] = 26;
$qryVals = implode(",",$my_array);
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN($qryVals)";
echo $query;
?>
```